# Is combination of markdown and LaTeX a future trend of LaTeX development?

Tags: markdown, latex-misc

I think markdown language is encroaching on the market of LaTeX, could latex developers share about your opinions on this language? Do you think a kind of combination of markdown and LaTeX be a good idea?

For me, when I use Mou on my mac, I found some markdown editors are able to insert images quite nicely, so I was thinking if someday somehow it could even live preview the flowchart (including the TikZ in markdown), it would make life much easier. Isn't that the dream of original LaTeX project?

Comment: I think that using markdown as the primary "language" and converting this to LaTeX down the road is an interesting idea. However, as it stands, it is difficult to tell what is being asked here. "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."…tex.SE FAQ

Comment: It's already possible to write documents in a mix of LaTeX and markdown, using [Pandoc's markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#raw-tex).